# ActiveAdmin: undefined method 'unscoped'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, activeadmin, rails-activerecord

I have a model where the default scope shows only records with status set to 0:

> default_scope where(status: 0)

This works fine, and when I display all the records in an ActiveAdmin page, it only the shows the ones with a status of 0. However, I would like to create another page in the admin panel that shows all the records, unscoped. Right now, I have:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Donation, as: "All Donations" do

  scope_to :unscoped

  index :title => "Donations" do
    ...
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `unscoped' for #<Admin::AllDonationsController:0x007feac043d638>
```

This still seems to happen if I give the scope a different name in the model. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What's your version of ActiveAdmin?  There was a similar issue a while back: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/70

Comment: I'm using version 0.6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get what I wanted by adding this to the register block for donations:

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    Donation.unscoped
  end
end
```

I still don't understand why ActiveAdmin can't see scopes you define in the model file

Comment: Andrew how to unscoped joins. I've used `default_scope -> { kept }` to get all records except discarded. I want all records with or without discarded. Here is my query `Payout.unscoped.joins("INNER JOIN payments ON payments.id = payouts.payment_id").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN virtual_accounts ON payments.mode_id = virtual_accounts.id").where("payments.mode_type = 'VirtualAccount'").where("payments.discarded_at IS NULL OR payments.discarded_at IS NOT NULL").where("virtual_accounts.discarded_at IS NULL OR virtual_accounts.discarded_at IS NOT NULL")`